# docker compose flyway not connecting to postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, flyway

When running `docker compose up`, I only get output from my postgres docker container. It seems that the flyway container is not even attempting to connect to the postgres container. I have also tried to run a standalone flyway docker container from the terminal and attempt to connect to postgres, but I get connection refused error ( more info below).
Im not sure what I'm missing here?

```
# Use postgres/example user/password credentials
version: '3'

services:
  flyway:
    image: flyway/flyway
    command: -url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/restra -user=restra -password=restra -connectRetries=60 migrate
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/resources/db/migrations:/flyway/sql

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=restra # database with same name created automatically
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=restra #password MUST be set, cannot be blank
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-U", "restra" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 1s
      retries: 2
```

I get this output after doing `docker compose up`

```
restra-db-1      | ********************************************************************************
restra-db-1      | WARNING: POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD has been set to "trust". This will allow
restra-db-1      |          anyone with access to the Postgres port to access your database without
restra-db-1      |          a password, even if POSTGRES_PASSWORD is set. See PostgreSQL
restra-db-1      |          documentation about "trust":
restra-db-1      |          https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
restra-db-1      |          In Docker's default configuration, this is effectively any other
restra-db-1      |          container on the same system.
restra-db-1      | 
restra-db-1      |          It is not recommended to use POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust. Replace
restra-db-1      |          it with "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" instead to set a password in
restra-db-1      |          "docker run".
restra-db-1      | ********************************************************************************
restra-db-1      | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
restra-db-1      | This user must also own the server process.
restra-db-1      | 
restra-db-1      | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
restra-db-1      | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
restra-db-1      | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
restra-db-1      | 
restra-db-1      | Data page checksums are disabled.
restra-db-1      | 
restra-db-1      | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
restra-db-1      | creating subdirectories ... ok
restra-db-1      | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
restra-db-1      | selecting default max_connections ... 100
restra-db-1      | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
restra-db-1      | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
restra-db-1      | creating configuration files ... ok
restra-db-1      | running bootstrap script ... ok
restra-db-1      | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
restra-db-1      | syncing data to disk ... ok
restra-db-1      | 
restra-db-1      | 
restra-db-1      | Success. You can now start the database server using:
restra-db-1      | 
restra-db-1      |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
restra-db-1      | 
restra-db-1      | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
restra-db-1      | initdb: hint: You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
restra-db-1      | waiting for server to start....2023-05-10 17:38:59.384 UTC [49] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
restra-db-1      | 2023-05-10 17:38:59.413 UTC [49] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
restra-db-1      | 2023-05-10 17:38:59.518 UTC [52] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-05-10 17:38:57 UTC
restra-db-1      | 2023-05-10 17:38:59.565 UTC [49] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
restra-db-1      |  done
restra-db-1      | server started
restra-db-1      | CREATE DATABASE
restra-db-1      | 
restra-db-1      | 
restra-db-1      | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
restra-db-1      | 
restra-db-1      | 2023-05-10 17:39:00.046 UTC [49] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
restra-db-1      | waiting for server to shut down....2023-05-10 17:39:00.085 UTC [49] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
restra-db-1      | 2023-05-10 17:39:00.089 UTC [49] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 55) exited with exit code 1
restra-db-1      | 2023-05-10 17:39:00.090 UTC [50] LOG:  shutting down
restra-db-1      | 2023-05-10 17:39:00.120 UTC [50] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
restra-db-1      | 2023-05-10 17:39:00.680 UTC [50] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 918 buffers (5.6%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.153 s, sync=0.272 s, total=0.590 s; sync files=250, longest=0.216 s, average=0.002 s; distance=4217 kB, estimate=4217 kB
restra-db-1      | 2023-05-10 17:39:00.699 UTC [49] LOG:  database system is shut down
restra-db-1      |  done
restra-db-1      | server stopped
restra-db-1      | 
restra-db-1      | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
restra-db-1      | 
restra-db-1      | 2023-05-10 17:39:00.896 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
restra-db-1      | 2023-05-10 17:39:00.896 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
restra-db-1      | 2023-05-10 17:39:00.896 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
restra-db-1      | 2023-05-10 17:39:00.971 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
restra-db-1      | 2023-05-10 17:39:01.074 UTC [65] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-05-10 17:39:00 UTC
restra-db-1      | 2023-05-10 17:39:01.122 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

I also tried to run the flyway docker container from command line to test the connection to the postgres docker container from flyway (found on the official flyway github page :https://github.com/flyway/flyway-docker) .

```
docker run --rm flyway/flyway -url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/restra -user=restra -password=restra info
```

Then I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/restra) for user 'restra': Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 08001
Error Code : 0
Message    : Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `--network="host"` to your `docker run` command:

```
docker run --rm --network="host" flyway/flyway -url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/restra -user=restra -password=restra info
```